# How can I add non-Google accounts as editors in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Apps Script to control access to documents however when trying to add a non-google account (using [addEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addEditor(String))) I get a Stackdriver error of 'Invalid email: email@example.com at addEditors(Code:120)' and the email address is not added as an editor of the target document. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that, a gmail account is must. Probably not what you want but you can give access 'To Anyone with the link'

Answer (score 1):

Editors should use a Google account. If users you want to include haven't a Google account you could add them as viewers.

From [Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en)

> Note: If you share with an email address that isn’t a Google Account, they’ll only be able to view the file.